# c# autocad set ucs z axis

Tags: c#, autocad

my google-fu is weak concerning setting the autocad ucs z axis. i've seen many examples online for defining a ucs though none that set the z axis. i can manually set the z axis by command line typing 'ucs' then 'za' and picking 2 point to define the z axis.

i tried this:
[Align the UCS to an entity](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/align-the-ucs-to-an-entity.html)

which did not work as i need it to. i also tried modifying this but i am obviously missing some knowledge of C# to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why did it not work as you need it to? Since you tried modifying, what exactly did you try?

Comment: i replaced the following lines in the code:
                //Line ent = Tx.GetObject(res.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Line;
                Solid ent = Tx.GetObject(SelObjId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Solid;

                // get the ucs from the entity
                Matrix3d ecs = new Matrix3d();

                // set the direction of the 
                //Vector3d xVec = (ent.EndPoint - ent.StartPoint);
                Vector3d xVec = (SelObjEndPt - SelObjStartPt);

Comment: You should put that in your question. You also haven't explained what didn't work for you.

Comment: the code does not allow for a way to set the z axis in a particular direction. the code in the link does not align the z axis with the line, which is what i thought it did.

Comment: You need to put these things in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extension method:

```
public static class EditorExtension
{
    public static void SetZAxisUcs (this Editor ed, Point3d basePoint, Point3d positiveZaxisPoint)
    {
        Plane plane = new Plane(basePoint, basePoint.GetVectorTo(positiveZaxisPoint));
        Matrix3d ucs = Matrix3d.PlaneToWorld(plane);
        ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem = ucs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks gileCAD. it did not occur to me to investigate setting it via the basepoint. this works cleanly.